# MVC3 authorization using AD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, authorization

Is it possible to authorise/deny users of an MVC3 application using AD?

My app is secured using Windows authentication at the moment, but that means adding users to groups on the Win2007 server.

I'd like to change that so that users were allowed/denied access to the appliction/and controller actions/view based upon their AD roles instead, so they either auto-logged in (like Windows auth) or they get redirected to a "denied" page.

Any help very gratefully accepted...everything I find seems to be based upon Windows groups, or forms authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Roles property:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"SOMEDOMAIN\somegroup")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ...
}
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs) which explains the steps.

Comment: so in my example is setting up the `AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider` superfluous? it should "just-work" with enabling WindowsAuth?

Comment: I saw the tutorial, but it suggests those are Win2k7 "roles" and not AD ones.  Also, can you stop ANY access to the site with "roles"?  e.g. admin/users can access site, admin can access further pages, everyone else hits "unauthorised" page?

Comment: If your user is authenticated on the domain from AD, the WindowsToken includes the groups assigned from AD.  
You can definitely block all access with Roles; well, you could apply the AuthorizeAttribute to each controller.

Comment: Thankyou Hometoast:  Final stupid question - How do I set the entire site to only alow certain roles?  Do I just put "Allow" "\\domain\usergroup\"  in webconfig?

Comment: @BlueChippy, you could register AuthorizeAttribute as global action filter in `Global.asax`: `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute { Roles = @"SOMEDOMAIN\somegroup" });`. I would avoid using the Allow section in web.config to control authorization in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: @Darin, what would the difference be between "allow" and "filter"?  I'd like non-authourised users to see a "not authorised" page and to very quickly add/remove groups without having to re-compile/re-deploy if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using AD Groups for my intranet app.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

then just added Authorization attributes to my controller actions that I needed to secure:

```
[Authorize(Roles = MyNamesspace.Constants.MANAGER_GROUP)]
public ActionResult Blah() {...
```

And in a view you can use `User.IsInRole` and the name of their AD/Windows group.

Or get a list of the roles the webserver sees from that user: `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser();`

Caveat: my server and my clients are all on the same domain. this won't work if you need to do the same for web clients off site against your ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) framework that comes built-in to Asp.net.  You will find that there is already an [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) out of the box, but you will have to implement the `RoleProvider` yourself, as membership can be defined different ways in different networks.