# how to authenticate against windows local users and groups

Tags: authentication

I have a user set up in windows users and groups as username/pwd in group1. How do it validate against it? The article [how to list windows users and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515588/how-to-list-windows-users-and-groups-in-asp-net) tells how to list them.

How do I validate against a local user inside a group w/ password?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are not looking at using the Windows impersonation but rather a login box for your users and authenticate against both a local source and fallback to AD. If so then these answers should point you in the right direction: [MVC3 authorization using AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101330/mvc3-authorization-using-ad)

If you prefer VB.NET then the CodeProject appears to have a [good article on AD authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42428/ASP-NET-3-5-Custom-Windows-Authentication-using-VB).

Comment: I'm not using AD authentication. I just need to verify than username/pwd match with a user called user1 in a group called group1. I can easily find out a member inside a group, but not sure how to validate against the pwd.